# RxJS: Run asynchronous code before next or error

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
of(true)
  .pipe(
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe(async (_) =>  {
    await this.close();
    await Promise.all(...);
  }, _ => {
    this.close();
    console.error(_);
  });
```

I want to only write once `this.close()`, however I can't use `finalize` since it has to be run before `Promise.all`. Is there something I could use to run a code (and wait for it to resolve) before `next` or `error` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I could use to run a code (and wait for it to resolve) before next or error

I think `materialize()` and `dematerialize()` can be useful here:

```js
src$.pipe(
  // Suppress errors so that `delayWhen()` can run properly
  // by converting everything into `Notification` objects
  materialize(),

  // Wait until `close()` finishes
  delayWhen(() => this.close())

  // Convert from `Notification` to the initial state: `next` || `error` || `complete`
  // so that their handlers can be invoked accordingly
  dematerialize(),
)
```

Note that with this approach it is going to wait for a `complete` notification as well, which can be avoided with the help of `filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could emit a value on error with `catchError`. This way your `next` callback will be executed when an error occurs.

```ts
const ERROR_TOKEN = 'my-error';

of(true).pipe(
  take(1),
  catchError(_ => {
    console.error(_);
    return of(ERROR_TOKEN); // emit some kind of error value
  })
)
.subscribe(async (value) =>  {
  // do on normal and error value
  await this.close();
  if (value !== ERROR_TOKEN) {
    // only do on normal values
    await Promise.all(...);
  }
});
```

---

Or write a custom operator that merges your async code into the stream.

```ts
function awaitOnNextAndError<T, R extends ObservableInput<any>>(
  asyncOnNextAndError: () => R,
  sideEffectOnError?: (e) => void
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  // only run your async code on 'subscribe' and ignore its output
  const pre = defer(() => asyncOnNextAndError()).pipe(ignoreElements())
  return (source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(
    // do some side effect on errors immediately, e.g. logging
    tap({ error: sideEffectOnError }),
    // execute your async code before you continue with the value from the stream
    mergeMap(v => concat(pre, of(v))),
    // execute your async code on error
    catchError(e => pre)
  )
}

of(true).pipe(
  take(1),
  awaitOnNextAndError(() => this.close(), console.error)
)
.subscribe(async (_) => {
  await Promise.all(...);
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-efscr8